# Connecting Intel RealSense d435 camera

Tags: computer-vision, ros, robotics, raspberry-pi4, realsense

I'm working on a robotics-related project and I want to connect an *Intel RealSense d435* camera to a *raspberry pi 4* with *ROS Kinetic*.

Any links on how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You could start by searching these links in this order:

- Installing [Ubuntu in your Raspberri](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi). Please install Ubuntu 16.04 since the wrapper for your kinect will use this Ubuntu for ROS Kinectic.
- Tutorial to use [Raspberry Pi 4 and Intel RealSense D435](https://github.com/acrobotic/Ai_Demos_RPi/wiki/Raspberry-Pi-4-and-Intel-RealSense-D435)
  . Another related question answered in the [official website](https://support.intelrealsense.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360048495493--Intel-Realsense-D435-with-RaspberryPi-Best-practice-installation-guide).
- ROS [Wrapper for Intel® RealSense™ Devices](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros). These are packages for using Intel RealSense cameras (D400 series).

The concrete steps are well detailed in the links.